# How do I run .sh?

Tags: usb, scripts

I checked *Allow executing file as program.*, but is still open in editor. Ubuntu is installed on USB.

Comment: Go to the terminal (CTRL + ALT + t), find the file, go to the folder where the file is using `cd my_folder` and then `./.sh`